# how to email database and form values

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a website created using PHP to store form values in a database, and have a page that displays the values for certain users based on the selections.  I am trying to send these values from the database to an email address, but I can not separate the values on each line of the subject.  I am using the PHP built in function to email and storing the values in the subject variable.

I have tried add each variable separately by using

```
$subject . "content";
```

for each variable but it still is all in one line.

I am now thinking of making a newsletter type, but can't figure out how to make one or make it work how I want.  So if anyone could help out on how I can send these values either in this way or in a different language.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
   $query= sql query
    $resultt= sql result
    $roww=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultt);

    extract($roww);

    $emmessage = "User Form Information";

    $emmessage = $emmessage . "     " . "values extracted from the database from $roww

$send = @$_POST['send'];
$subject = strip_tags(@$_POST['subject']);
$reciever= strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$message = $emmessage;

//  Start email processing
if ($send) 
{
//  Send the message
mail($reciever, $subject, $message, "From: $email");
$emessage="Your message has been sent";
include("forme.php");
```

Comment: Please supply some code so we can help you (otherwise you run the risk of getting down voted & potentially getting this question closed).

Comment: Edited it with code I am using.

Answer (score 1):

You can used `br2nl()` function. Or if you are used `\n` directly as suggested before you should use `nl2br()` function so that in HTML page you will get a new line instead of a `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate lines in e-mails using `\n`.

```
$content = "Value 1 \n Value2";
```

Comment: i tried that and the message was still on one line and it had "\n" where I had written in the variable.